# how to remove attribure error on using iloc function for dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to set 0 value for the column 'fare_amount' based on specified conditions in iloc, ended up getting attribute error. 'dataset' is Dataframe object.

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'

```
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset['fare_amount'] != 0 & dataset['passenger_count'] == 0, 'fare_amount'] = 0
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is `dataset` here?

Comment: That implies that your variable `dataset` is of type `int`.  Try `type(dataset)` to confirm and find the issue upstream.

Comment: The problem is your second `=` assignment setting the whole thing equal to zero

Comment: 'dataset' is of DataFrame type

Answer (score 1):

Check what you are doing,

```
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset['fare_amount'] != 0 & dataset['passenger_count'] == 0, 'fare_amount'] = 0
```

You are writing dataset **=** ... **=** 0.So you are puting '**=**' two times. You should do this:

```
dataset.loc[dataset['fare_amount'] != 0 & dataset['passenger_count'] == 0, 'fare_amount'] = 0
```

Comment: On doing that, I am getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`